# jq: error (at <stdin>:4): Cannot index string with string "ParameterKey"

Tags: jq

test.sh is not replacing test.json parameter value  and gives jq compilation error.

### test.json

```
{
  "ParameterKey": "Project",
  "ParameterValue": "<check>"
 }
```

### test.sh

```
cat test.json | jq \
'map(if .ParameterKey == "Project" 
    then . + {"ParameterValue" : "val" } 
else . end)' > result.json
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're seeing that message is that the [`map()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#map(x),map_values(x)) expression is enumerating the values of your object ("`Project`" and "`<check>`") invoking the `if .ParameterKey ...` expression on each of them. Unfortunately those are strings and the `.ParameterKey` part of your `if` condition won't work with string values so jq gives you the error `Cannot index string with string “ParameterKey”`.

You probably only want the `map()` if your `test.json` contains an array of objects. If your `test.json` contains an object at the top level such as `{"ParameterKey": "Project", "ParameterValue": "<check>"}` then you should remove the `map()`.  e.g.

```
$ cat test.json | \
  jq 'if .ParameterKey == "Project" then . + {"ParameterValue" : "val" }  else . end'
{
  "ParameterKey": "Project",
  "ParameterValue": "val"
}
```